# How to resolve this fractional equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help and explain how can i resolve this equation?

$$1650=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}}$$

Comment: (1) Write it down here, (2) That equation seems to involve two unknowns. The solution for it can, in general, be only parametric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for solutions in integers?  The equation simplifies to

$$ x_1 x_2 = 1650 (x_1 + x_2) $$
(where we don't want $x_1 + x_2 = 0$),
or
$$(x_1 - 1650)(x_2 - 1650) = 1650^2$$
For any integer $d$ dividing $1650^2$ (except $-1650$), we can then take $x_1 = 1650 + d$, $x_2 = 1650 + 1650^2/d$.